# foreign culture XML text parsing

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, exception, xna

I have released a windows phone app a while back. Since then, BugSense reported a problem that is causing some crashes in foreign countries:

> System.ArgumentException - The character 'İ' (0x0130) is not available
>   in this SpriteFont. If applicable, adjust the font's start and end
>   CharacterRegions to include this character. Parameter name: character

and here is the stack trace:

> at
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteFont.GetIndexForCharacter(Char
>   character) at
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteFont.InternalMeasure(StringProxy&
>   text) at
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteFont.MeasureString(String text)
>   at GlobalEngine.Visual.TextBase.CalculateSpriteOrigin(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   at GlobalEngine.Visual.TextBase.set_FormattedText(String value) at
>   GlobalEngine.Visual.TextLabel.set_Text(String value) at
>   FourWordsLibrary.GameUtils.Letter..ctor(Char letter, AssetManager
>   assetManager, SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Single width) at
>   FourWordsLibrary.GameUtils.Word..ctor(String orderedWord, String
>   shuffledWord, AssetManager assetManager, SpriteBatch spriteBatch,
>   InputManager inputManager, Single letterWidth) at
>   FourWordsLibrary.GameUtils.Word..ctor(String orderedWord, String
>   shuffledWord, AssetManager assetManager, SpriteBatch spriteBatch,
>   InputManager inputManager) at
>   FourWordsLibrary.Controllers.GameControl.StatePlay.SetupNextLevel() at
>   FourWordsLibrary.Controllers.GameControl.StatePlay.Activate(Object
>   obj) at GlobalEngine.Base.StateManager`1.SetState(T state, Object obj)
>   at GlobalEngine.Base.StateManager`1.SetState(T state) at
>   FourWordsLibrary.Controllers.GameControl.SetPack(PackManager
>   packManager) at FourWords.Screens.GameScreen..ctor(Engine engine,
>   Object obj)

My app is a word game, and I retrieve the words for each level from an XML file. So I suspect that as the XmlReader is reading the file, it does so using a foreign culture which results in with a Latin letter being retrieved, then the app crashes when it tries to draw the letter using a strictly English sprite-font.
I tried looking for a way to instruct the XmlReader to read using InvariantCulture, similar to that found in the .toString() method, but haven't found any. Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: I have a similar issue, did you ever figure out how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems more an input XML file problem to me. Check if it contains this 'invalid' character ('İ' (0x0130) ) and correct it if necessary. If you wrote the input XML using your app/game, check if you are writing the contents using InvariantCulture as well.

Br,

Comment: I found no such character in my XML document. I create and populate my XML file using a basic editor I created in WPF, where I type the words into basic text boxes. The words are then written into the XML using the StreamWriter object, which doesn't seem to take any arguments relating to culture.

Comment: Check your editor where you are writing the words from text boxes, you can call .ToString().ToUpperInvariant() for example (if you are using only uppercase letters). Otherwise call .ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) Would also help if you can post a small XML sample