# C#/XNA Culture Issue

Tags: c#, xml, xna, cultureinfo

My application doesn't load levels properly on computers with different cultures.

If I change the Thread culture to InvariantCulture I can reproduce the issue on my computer

I think it is failing at reading XML information, some assets seem to get loaded in that by coincidence don't break the culture.

I'm using a StreamReader, XmlDocument and XmlNode, I've tried formatting to InvariantCulture but to no avail.

I don't get any error messages, it seems to load and start the game properly but many tiles are missing.

Has anyone come across the same issue and figured out a solution?

This seems to be a very similar issue, although I'm not getting any exceptions since I'm not using fonts;

[foreign culture XML text parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980884/foreign-culture-xml-text-parsing?rq=1)

Comment: Do your map names (or content) contain culture specific characters?

Comment: No, but I have read Swedish culture sorts 'v' and 'w' differently from other cultures and I think I see a connection that assets and properties that have no 'v' or 'w' load properly while those that do, don't'. And to be clear my native culture is Swedish

Comment: I'm thinking I need to define the culture of the thread reading the XML.

Answer (score 0):

By defining the culture of the thread myself, in this case forcing it to be Swedish on all computers the issue was solved.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-SE");
```